# Java endless list

Tags: java, list, collections

I think it is a standard problem. I need a list that I can iterate for and backward. If iterating forward and the iterator riches e.g. 80% of length of the list, new element must be added to the end of list and the same number of elements must be deleted from the beginning of list. This should happen during iteration without influencing the iterator. The current iterator should be still valid. The same procedures should work, if the iterator goes backward.
Is there any kind of list, queue or stack in any collection that fulfills these requirements? Anybody know?

Thx

Comment: You can create your own ListIterator class

Comment: That's a very specific request, you'll almost certainly have to implement that yourself. Also your list can't be infinite because you'll end up running out of memory.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a standard problem to me.  But anyway, whay have you managed to implement so far?

Comment: The simplest solution is likely to use an `int index` which can be decremented or incremented as you need.

Comment: BTW https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue supports an unbounded, indexable list of entries which is only limited by your disk space.  This is likely to be overkill however.

Answer (score 0):

this can be very easily implemented using array.

1. Set initial size of the array.
2. Create Array of that size and you desired type
3. Create index (int for example) which is incremented/decreased when iterating the array.
4. Add logic to track the index (e.g. if index>0.8*size -> add more elements to the array)

I would use the java ArrayList object for this job.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is not an endless list, but a circular list (endless list would not delete from the beginning).

What you want is a function with a normal list inside, that takes an iterator as parameter and just rolls over when it reaches the end. So element 101 of 100 element list, is element 1 being overwritten.